# Minimal area of quadrilateral divided by its shorter diagonal

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Given four sides $a,b,c,d$, which konvex quadrilateral with these sides minimizes $\frac{\sqrt{A}}{f}$, where $A$ denotes the area and $f$ the shorter diagonal.

My guess is, that it is minimized by the cyclic quadrilateral, due to the case where all sides have the same length but I have no clue if this is true for the general case and how to prove it.

Comment: Is the order of $a,b,c,d$ fixed?

Comment: Yes. But if there is an approach if they are not fixed I would also be interested.

Comment: Does it help to note that when $\frac{\sqrt{A}}{f} = \sqrt{\frac{A}{f^2}}$ is minimized, $\frac{A}{f^2}$ and $\frac{A^2}{f^4}$ are also minimized, and vice versa, because $0 \lt \frac{A}{f} \in \mathbb{R}$ for a non-degenerate quadrilateral (which is a requirement for the ratio to be finite)?  And that given semiperimeter $s = \frac{1}{2}(a + b + c + d)$ the area of the quadrilateral with diagonals $f \le g$ is $A = \sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)+\frac{1}{4}(ac+bd+fg)(ac+bd-fg)}$? And that WLOG $a = 1$?

Comment: Some casual experimentation shows the given quantity is not minimized when the quadrilateral is cyclic. Instead, it seems that the minimum is reached when the diagonals have the same length, or at least the difference of their lengths is minimal.

Comment: Glärbo, I think it should be $A = \sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)-\frac{1}{4}(ac+bd+fg)(ac+bd-fg)}$.
 Intelligenti pauca, this seems reasonable.

Comment: I think I have a proof for this claim if $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d) \geq \frac{(ac+bd)^2}{4}$. I claim this is true iff $a,b,c,d$ admit a convex quadrilateral where the diagonals have equal length. Anyone knows if this claim is true? 
The case if it does not admit such a quadrilateral should be quite easy then.

Comment: Your claim fails, for instance, for $a=d=4$, $b=3$, $c=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has no simple answer. To see this consider two easy solvable examples:

1. Orthodiagonal quadrilateral: $a^2+c^2=b^2+d^2$. In this case the minimizing quadrilateral is that one with equal diagonals (or with the diagonal ratio possibly closest to $1$ if the ratio $1$ is not allowed by the convexity requirement).
2. "Degenerable" quadrilateral: $a+b=c+d$, $a\ne d$. In this case the minimizing quadrilateral is the degenerate one with the minimizing value being $0$.

Generally the minimizing quantity is
$$
\frac{2A}{q^2}=\frac pq\sin\theta,
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are the longer and the shorter diagonals, respectively, and $\theta$ is the angle between the diagonals. Obviously for a constant angle (as in the first example) the minimum will be achieved at $p=q$, but in some cases (as in the second example) the decrease of the angle $\theta$ can be decisive.